# Interpolating a changing value based on time (glsl)

Tags: javascript, glsl, shader

I have a uniform in my vertex shader with a value that can change from 0 to 1, without interpolation. However, I want it interpolated over time, but I don't want to do this in Javascript (from the CPU). I want it interpolated from 0 to 1 (or back) when it changes (which happens on certain user input).

(I do have a incrementing `uTime` uniform that I suppose I can use for this problem)?

I hope this explains my question clear enough. TIA.

Comment: You will need to tell the vertex shader what the direction of travel is, is it being enabled or disabled, because it doesn't know what the previous state was. The rest you can do with your time uniform.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, do you mean as passing another uniform or storing the previous state in a variable? @Andrea

Comment: I was thinking the former, but come to think of it, you could actually track the state changes using some type of persistent storage the shader can write to and read from (e.g. `shared` or SSBOs).

Comment: Interesting, but I guess I'll have to try sending along another uniform, I'm using WebGL 1, I'm not quite sure if I have the option to use SSBOs yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose, that `uTime` contains the time in milliseconds. Dividing the value by a timespan, gives a value that increments by 1 in the timespan.
The fractional part of that value continuously changes from 0.0 to 1.0 and starts again at 0.0. The the fractional part of a number can be computed by [`fract`](http://docs.gl/el3/fract). e.g:
(if the unit of `uTime` is secondes, then the `timespan` has to be 3.0)

```c
uniform float uTime; // time in milliseconds

void main()
{
    const float timespan = 3000.0; // e.g. 3 seconds
    float w = fract(uTime / timespan);

    // [...]
}
```

For a [Hermite interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation) use additionally [`smoothstep`](http://docs.gl/el3/smoothstep):

```c
uniform float uTime; // time in milliseconds

void main()
{
    const float timespan = 3000.0; // e.g. 3 seconds
    float w = smoothstep(0.0, 1.0, fract(uTime / timespan));

    // [...]
}
```

Another nice effect can be achieved by using [`sin`](http://docs.gl/el3/sin). [Sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine) gives a value that continuously changes between -1.0 and 1.0 dependent on the angle in [Radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) [0.0, 2*PI] e.g.:

```c
uniform float float uTime; // time in milliseconds

void main()
{
    const float timespan = 3000.0; // e.g. 3 seconds
    float w = sin(2.0 * 3.14159 * uTime / timespan) * 0.5 + 0.5;

    // [...]
}
```

---

If you want to start the animation at a certain point of time, then you'll need a 2nd uniform variable (`uStartTime`), which indicates the time point. The variable has to have the same unit than `uTime`.
When ever the animation has to be started the set the value of `uStartTime`. At the begin its value is 0. If `uStartTime` is less or equal `uTime` then the animation is at 0.0. That is rare case and just for a moment, when `uStartTime` is set. It `uTime` is grater or equal than `uStartTime + timespan` than the animation is at 1.0. Instead of calculating the fractional part, you've to [`clamp`](http://docs.gl/el3/clamp%60) the difference of te current time and the start time to the range form 0.0 to 1.0. e.g.:

```c
uniform float uTime; // time in milliseconds
uniform float uStartTime; 

void main()
{
    const float timespan = 3000.0; // e.g. 3 seconds
    float w = clamp((uTime-uStartTime) / timespan, 0.0, 1.0);

    // [...]
}
```

---

If you want to set the interpolation direction(form 0 to 1 or 1 to 0), dependent on the "direction", the you'll need some additional information. Add another uniform variable (uTarget) of type `float` and set it either to 0.0 or 1.0. The value defines the interpolation target:

```c
uniform float uTime; // time in milliseconds
uniform float uStartTime; 
uniform float uTarget; // 0.0 or 1.0 

void main()
{
    const float timespan = 3000.0; // e.g. 3 seconds
    float w = clamp((uTime-uStartTime) / timespan, 0.0, 1.0);
    w = mix(1.0-w, w, uTarget);

    // [...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice and detailed answer. uTime is indeed the time in milliseconds. Didn't think of using the fractal part of this uniform for interpolation.. 

However, I guess it doesn't really fully answer my question, this makes clear how to use the uTime uniform for interpolation, but what I really want is the interpolation to happen whenever my value changes, in the right direction..

Comment: Thanks for the edit! So as I understand it, `uStartTime` starts at 0. I should then set `uStartTime` in milliseconds (same unit) every time my value changes? As `uStartTIme` does a comparison to `uTime`, which keeps increasing, do I need to calculate a specific value based on `uTime` or could it be 1 and 0?

Comment: @FabianTjoeAOn All you've to do is to set `uStartTime` when your value changes. Set the same time as you set to `uTime`. `uTime` is set in every frame, but `uStartTime` is set when the value changes only.

Comment: Yep, this works :). However, interpolation is now one directional, it only interpolates from 0 to 1, how can I get it to interpolate in both directions based on the changing value (so not `uTime`, but the value that changes 1 to 0 and back)?

Comment: @FabianTjoeAOn You want that the value changes 0 -> 1 -> 0, every time when the direction changes? Or do you mean it has to changed based on the direction 0 -> 1 respectively 1 -> 0?

Comment: I mean the latter, so when my value changes from 0 -> 1, interpolate from 0 to 1. It then stays 1. Then value changes from 1 -> 0, interpolate from 1 to 0.